# grails test-app integration coverage giving error

Tags: grails

My code

```
def baseRecordList = DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers",[cache: false])
```

is giving the below error inside `PriorApprovalController.groovy`

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: DealerBaseInfo.findAll() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), findAll(java.lang.Object), findAll(java.lang.String), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)
at DealerBaseInfo.findAll(DealerBaseInfo.groovy)
at DealerBaseInfo$findAll.call(Unknown Source)
PriorApprovalController.<init>(PriorApprovalController.groovy:37)
... 42 more
| Error Exception occurred trigger event [TestPhasesEnd]: Could not create a new instance of class [PriorApprovalController]!`
```

grails version is 2.1.1 and code-coverage plugin 1.2.5
Why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the findAll() supported signatures: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html

To use the queryParams, I think you should do something like this:

```
def baseRecordList = DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers", [], [cache: false])
```

Comment: not working giving same error DealerBaseInfo.list() also not working giving same error i think error is with that coverage because test-app integration is working fine

Comment: I see. Let us know if you can solve it. PS. I would move that code in a service, rather than a controller, as it's business logic.

Comment: after moving code to service it is giving null pointer exception for the service code java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method queryResult() on null object service code is class QueryService {

   def queryResult(){
       return DealerBaseInfo.findAll("from DealerBaseInfo as dealers",[cache: false])
   }
} and controller code is def baseRecordList = queryService.queryResult()

Comment: Can you update the question putting a bit more code in there? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

actually the error was coming because of class level access of findAll method i have written a static method in domain for findAll and access that method in controller then it worked